# How to manually allow external access to ports 14141 TCP and UDP in linux 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ip, tcp-ip

I require external access to ports 14141 TCP and UDP. I need to manually allow access to these ports.

I am an absolute beginner. Detailed steps would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu by default has no firewall, and to do this requires you to do port forwarding at your router (which has nothing to do with Ubuntu typically)

Comment: How can I do port forwarding? I am really sorry if this is a basic question, I have no idea of Computer Networks.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Port forwarding is something that is router specific (although the concept is the same). In short, you "map" (or "forward") traffic from the Internet that hits your router on a certain port (or ports) to an IP address and port on your local area network (or "home network"). Just do a search for: "<your_router_make/model> port forwarding".

Comment: Here's an example search for how to set up port forwarding on a Superhub 3: [https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Superhub+3+port+fowarding](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Superhub+3+port+fowarding)